# Tint color for UIBarButtonItem doesn't change on device

Tags: objective-c

I've changed tint color for UINavigationBar(to black color) and UIBarButtonItem (to blue color) in XIB.
On simulator it presents good but on device navigation bar and button item are black.

How to fix the following issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you changed UIBarButtonItem color when you are initializing it program ?

Comment: I've changed tint color in XIB (NOT programmatically)

Comment: It's still not working. I use SDK 5.0 and deploy on device with iOS 4.2

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> tintColor
>
> The tint color for the button item. @property(nonatomic, retain)
>   UIColor *tintColor Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIBarButtonItem.h

You are seeing the tint color being set in Interface Builder because you have SDK 5.0. However, when you run the program on iOS 4, tint color is ignored. Tint color can only be set for iOS 5. One hack is to not use a UIBarButtonItem, but rather a normal UIButton. Since UIButtons cannot be placed in a toolbar, you'll have to fake it by placing it as a sibling of the toolbar and positioning it over the toolbar.